# Как вывести каждую строку текстового?

Tags: node.js

Начал работать с модулем fs node.js

Есть следующий код:

```
    client.on('message', function(message) {
if (message.content === "$loop") { 
    var fs = require('fs');
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("keys.txt", "utf8");
    var interval = setInterval (function () {
        message.channel.send(fileContent)
        .catch(console.error);
    }, 1 * 1000); 
}
});
```

По логике, на каждой строке в документе стоят цифры 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Мне нужно, чтобы каждую секунду, что указано в setInterval, выводилась каждая новая строка. Первую секунду - первая, ещё через секунду - вторая. А как только закончатся строки, тормоза.

Comment: Вернее,если быть корректным. Сейчас выводятся все строки с пробелами
1
2
3
4
5

а нужно:
21:05:01 - время
1
21:05:02 - время
2
и тд..

Comment: А почему бы в таком случае не считать весь файл в строку, не разбить по пробелам с запятой и не совершить задуманное? Счётчик и массив чисел будете хранить снаружи, а внутри выводить данные и перемещать счётчик. И конечно же не забудьте остановить интервал, когда массив к концу подойдёт

Comment: Как жаль, что я ничего не понял из Ваших слов..

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!
let fileContent = fs.readFile('keys.txt', { encoding : 'utf8' },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    data.split('\n').forEach(line => {
    var interval = setInterval (function () {
        message.channel.send(line)
        .catch(console.error);
    }, 1 * 1000); 
   });
  });

Comment: Вот и молодец!! Удачи в изучении JS)